# Cakephp - Select2

Tags: php, database, cakephp, jquery-select2, cakephp-3.x

Can someone help me with multiple select in CakePHP 3?
I have a project in CakePHP 3.6. In one of the view, I need to add student's presences, and I wanna do it with a multiple select (Select2).

In one lesson I can choose many students. The students are saved in DB, and in the select input, I wanna get the students from there (DB).
I try to use **select2.org** script, but it does not work as I want. The input doesn't show the student's name.

This is my input:

```
echo $this->Form->input('students_id', [
                'type' => 'select', 
                'multiple' => true, 
                'options' => $students, 
                'hiddenField' => false,
                'id' => 'students_id', 
                ]);
```

This my script:

```
$('#students_id').select2({
    tag: true,
    multiple: 'multiple'
});
```

And in the controller I get students list in this way:

```
$students = $this->Students->find('list', ['limit' => 200]);
```

**EDIT:**

StudentsTable:

```
class StudentsTable extends Table
```

{

```
/**
 * Initialize method
 *
 * @param array $config The configuration for the Table.
 * @return void
 */
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);

    $this->setTable('students');
    $this->setDisplayField('name');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('id');

    $this->belongsTo('Courses', [
        'foreignKey' => 'course_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('LessonPresences', [
        'foreignKey' => 'student_id'
    ]);
}

/**
 * Default validation rules.
 *
 * @param \Cake\Validation\Validator $validator Validator instance.
 * @return \Cake\Validation\Validator
 */
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->integer('id')
        ->allowEmpty('id', 'create');

    $validator
        ->scalar('name')
        ->maxLength('name', 45)
        ->requirePresence('name', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('name');

    $validator
        ->scalar('lastname')
        ->maxLength('lastname', 45)
        ->requirePresence('lastname', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('lastname');

    $validator
        ->email('email')
        ->allowEmpty('email');

    $validator
        ->scalar('phone')
        ->maxLength('phone', 18)
        ->allowEmpty('phone');

    $validator
        ->integer('grander')
        ->allowEmpty('grander');

    $validator
        ->scalar('address')
        ->maxLength('address', 100)
        ->allowEmpty('address');

    $validator
        ->dateTime('add_date')
        ->requirePresence('add_date', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('add_date');

    $validator
        ->date('sign_date')
        ->requirePresence('sign_date', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('sign_date');

    $validator
        ->integer('status')
        ->allowEmpty('status');

    $validator
        ->date('course_end')
        ->allowEmpty('course_end');

    return $validator;
}
```

}

Comment: Propapbly you habe set students.id as display field in StudentsTable? Try to set the name with setDisplayField() of Table.

Comment: Can you please share your Students table?

Comment: I added the table above

Comment: What your output of $students?

Comment: A list:
$students = $this->Students->find('list', ['limit' => 200])

Comment: Does your select box format correctly if you don't use select2? If you are only selecting from the select2 box and not saving any new data, you don't need to use `tags` or `multiple` in the select2 script, just setting multiple to true in your ctp file will be sufficient.
As an aside `$this->Form->input()` has been deprecated, as you're using 3.6 you should use `$this->Form->control()`